# How Async operations in .Net Core becomes easy

Tags: asynchronous, asp.net-core, async-await, .net-core

I am researching about .Net core and when i saw that "It's easy to use async/await with .net Core" as a plus point.Still I  could not find any reason whats different between .Net and .Net Core async methods,Can someone explain it here please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing in .NET Core that would make it easier than full Framework to use `async`/`await`, because that is a language feature, not a framework feature.

I cannot comment on the random article you may have read. Maybe it was mistaken, maybe it compared .NET Core to non-.NET, or maybe it compared it to older versions or maybe it talked about ASP.NET Core which is *not* (necessarily) .NET Core, but rather the new version of ASP.NET.

Comment: Here is the Link
https://stackify.com/net-core-csharp-next-programming-language/

the content was like:
Here are some of .NET Core’s top features:

Strongly typed
Robust base class libraries
Asynchronous programming – easy to use async/await pattern
...

Comment: I don't think that article is comparing .NET Core with .NET Framework.

Comment: yes it should be, But when some one with .Net knowledge goes through with it ,it feels like it's new to .Net Core